# Error Installing ExpressJS via npm

Tags: node.js, express

I am running into an issue when I try to run "npm install -g express" and "npm install -g express-generator". Here is the error message for both. I have been able to install Express in the past by using package.json, but not through npm. Any ideas? :

"npm install -g express":

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express'
npm ERR! error rolling back  express@4.3.1 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express' }
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.2.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "express"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

"npm install -g express-generator":

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator/-/express-generator-4.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator/-/express-generator-4.2.0.tgz
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator'
npm ERR! error rolling back  express-generator@4.2.0 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator' }
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.2.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "express-generator"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Did you try sudo-ing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try with `sudo`? It looks like the current user does not have access to `/usr/local/lib`.

By the way, you want to install `express-generator` globally for the project generator nowadays, not the `express` package globally anymore.

Comment: Yep. All I needed to do was sudo.

Comment: sudo is all I need :)

Answer (score 0):

this is permission issue..

if you use without `sudo`, using this commandline..

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
```

[npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)

this link is best answer to you.

Answer (score 0):

Run cmd as Administrator and try installing it again. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
I had command "npm cache clean" -> not work
ulimit -n 2560 -> not work

so I 
delete .npm directory and run this command "npm search -g"
and removed some module -> in my case grunt*

that works for me.